# Is it possible to install the latests Firebase Crashlytics iOS SDK manually?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to migrate Crashlytics from Fabric to Firebase and in the documentation [Upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk) there is only a description for Cocoapods. I am not using Cocoapods in my project and don't want to, but I haven't found any alternative for installing the Firebase Crashlytics SDK. Does anyone has the same issue and found already a solution?

I have found this post from Saravana [How to add Firebase Crashlytics to iOS app](https://elsaravana.com/blog/how-to-add-firebase-crashlytics-to-ios-app/), but it is over one year old, so the SDK offered there is probably not the latest one.

This is my first question, please be kind :) And thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is also distributed as a [downloadable zip](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases) and via an [experimental Carthage distribution](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md).

Comment: Thanks for the information! That is the link I was looking for! The Carthage distribution would be great, but the "experimental" in the title sounds a little scary.

Answer (score 0):

So, after further research, there is a documentation for the installation without Cocoapods: [Add Firebase to your iOS project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks).